# Possible to mirror files in a folder, but don't delete

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to have some sort of tool to mirror all files written to a particular folder.

BUT, if that source folder deletes files, leave the mirror folder alone.

Answer (score 2):

Use windows scheduler to run [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) at a scheduled interval, it will only copy files with newer timestamps and therefore should leave it alone if it gets deleted.
Robocopy is built into W7

```
robocopy "C:\$data" "D:\Backup\$data" /FFT /e /r:0 /w:0
```

fft - timestamp
e - copies subfolders
r:0 and w:0 will skip over errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft's [Synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155), which will do exactly that.